# Multiple Controllers in the same module in Angular only one works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app with angularJS. I had a working solution, with a Login page and a Signup page, each page had its own module and controller file. I have restructured the app logic as shown below, to move both forms to my homepage. However, the signup controller isn't working, but the login does. What is going wrong?

HomepageController.js:

```
var login = angular.module('login', ['toastr', 'compareTo','ngMaterial']);
var signup = angular.module('signup', ['toastr', 'compareTo','ngMaterial']);
var HomepageModule = angular.module('HomepageModule', ['login', 'signup']);

login.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, toastr) {
    $scope.loginForm = {
    loading: false
  }

  $scope.submitLoginForm = function (){

  };
});

signup.controller('SignupController', function ($scope, $http, toastr) {
$scope.signupForm = {
    loading: false
  }

  $scope.submitSignupForm = function(){
    console.log("Create Account Pressed");
  };
});
```

homepage.ejs:

```
<body ng-app="HomepageModule" ng-cloak>
    <span ng-controller="LoginController">
        <form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()">
        <!-- Variuos inputs etc.-->
        </form>
    </span>
    <span ng-controller="SignupController">
        <form ng-submit="submitSignupForm()" id="sign-up-form" class="form-signin" name="signup"></form>
    </span>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: [Here's a working example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fv5HmzL3I7YsRw4gndB5?p=preview). You must be getting some kind of errors, I'm guessing involving your dependency injection. Also, you aren't closing several of your html elements, including the comment, but maybe that's just because you hastily created the code block.

Comment: I can see both are working in your plunker... btw which browser you are using?

Comment: @AshishBairagi Thank you, I think one of the tags was left open! I am using sublime